# Way to measure VCC internally for Arduino Sketch

Tags: arduino

Is there a signal in Arduino Sketch where the voltage in (VCC) is internally measured and provided to the MPU where it is accessible in code?  I've got an actuator with feedback but the this voltage never goes to GND or VCC (5.3 VCC and 4.9 feedback).  It would be nice to know what VCC is so I can know what the difference is.  I'm using the Tiny85 chip and it doesn't have a Vref input but uses VCC instead.

Comment: You can determine the VCC with the analog to digital count of the internal bandgap reference.

Comment: Jeff, can you point me in the right direction on how to get this reference?

Comment: In the Attiny85 Datasheet http://www.atmel.com/Images/atmel-2586-avr-8-bit-microcontroller-attiny25-attiny45-attiny85_datasheet.pdf section 8-3, page 43 describes it as: ATtiny25/45/85 features an internal bandgap reference. This reference is used for Brown-out Detection, and it can
be used as an input to the Analog Comparator or the ADC.

Answer (score 1):

A voltage of V<sub>CC</sub> measures 1023 when using V<sub>CC</sub> as the reference. Ground measures 0.